# is a SRAM XX 1 crankset compatible with an XT 8000 BB

Tags: crankset

can I put a SRAM XX 1 2x10 crankset into the BB of an XT 8000 (also 2x10)

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. GXP cranks need a left bearing with a 22mm ID, not 24 like Shimano.